# How to judge whether a certain URL has been opened in Google Chrome?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

i want use `npm install --save-dev open` to open my `local url` in development;

But every time a tab will be reopened,

So is there a way to judge whether Google Chrome has opened `local url` in NodeJs?

if exist in chrome i want to refresh my address! if not exist i will use open("http://localhost:3001") to open a new tab!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just working with chrome you could use npm [get-chrome-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-chrome-tabs) to get list of opened chrome tabs and check for the URL if its already opened.

If not then you can open it with [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open).